# Find position entry price from ID

Tags: pine-script

In Pine, if I made some `strategy.order` on a previous bar, with id `"order ID"`, is there a function to retreive the entry price of that order on a later bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strategy.closedtrades.entry_price` or `strategy.opentrades.entry_price`.

```
// Return the entry price for the latest  entry.
entryPrice = strategy.closedtrades.entry_price(strategy.closedtrades - 1)
```